# DBContextBuilder doesnot contain a definition for UseSqlServer in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm trying to implement microservices in .NET core framework (version 6.0) and facing this particular issue while adding the services of DBContext in the Program.CS file.

statement I'm using :

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProductContext>(options=>options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ProductDB")));
```

Error   CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlServer' and no accessible extension method 'UseSqlServer' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Micro   D:\NET_Micro\Micro\Micro\Program.cs 7   Active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These Errors occur usually when you are not including certain packages in your code.
Try downloading the following NuGet packages by running below mentioned code in your visual studio's package manager console :

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

```
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

and include them in your startup.cs/program.cs :

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to install the [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/) NuGet Package.

Then,  import the namespace with

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems there was a bug in VisualStudio 2022, had to restart and reinstall below packages to get it working:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer;
```